# Cython: how to make an python object as a property of cython class

Tags: python, c, class, binding, cython

I have a existing python class `X` and I want to do the followings:

```
from my_python_module import X
cdef class Y:
    cdef X test
```

But this does not work out of the box, the cdef only accepts C type, not a Python class. Any work-around ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I don't think you can (http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/sharing_declarations.html#sharing-extension-types) but you can work-around it using `__cinit__` to assert that the attribute has the correct type. The declaration `cdef public object x` of the extension type attribute has the following meaning:

- `cdef` is used [to declare attributes of Cython extension types](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/extension_types.html#introduction)
- `public` makes the [attribute accessible from Python code](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/extension_types.html#static-attributes)
- `object` is the type of the attribute, and [means that it is a Python object](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/language_basics.html#python-objects-as-parameters-and-return-values)
- `x` is the identifier of the attribute

In your Cython file (named "p.pyx" for example):

```
import my_python_module as q

cdef class Y:
    cdef int i
    cdef public object x  # public so it can be accessed from Python

    def __cinit__(self, x_):
        assert isinstance(x_, q.X)
        self.x = x_
```

and `my_python_module.py` is where you have defined your class X:

```
class X(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.i = 1
```

Then, you use it like this:

```
import my_python_module as q
import p

y = p.Y(q.X())
print y.x
print y.x.i
```

Also, note that `cpdef` means the same as `cdef` as of `cython == 0.29.22`, and will not be supported in `cython == 3` ([Cython issue 3959](https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/3959), and the [warning that `cython == 0.29.22` prints](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/cd6e29d0251b21d6b1b45f3de8eb452bcfe2cf68/Cython/Compiler/Nodes.py#L1428-L1429) if an attribute is declared with `cpdef`; see also the [changelog entry for that Cython version](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/changes.html)).

Comment: nice, so `object` can be used to assign any python object ?

Comment: @w00d: that's right (http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/language_basics.html#python-objects-as-parameters-and-return-values).

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like this:

```
cdef class SomeCls:
    cdef object _x

    def __cinit__(self, x_):
        self._x = x_

    property x:
        def __get__(self):
            return self._x
        def __set__(self, x_):
            self._x = x_
```

The above is especially useful when exposing attributes of an extern struct or class. Refer to example here:
[wrapping C++](http://docs.cython.org/0.14/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html#create-cython-wrapper-class)